# Error building esp-idf-template on Windows

Tags: python, windows, rust, esp32, esp-idf

I'm following the Rust on ESP guide [here](https://esp-rs.github.io/book/writing-your-own-application/generate-project-from-template.html). No matter which parameters I pick when generating the template, I always get:

```
  ERROR: This script was called from a virtual environment, can not create a virtual environment again
  Error: Could not install esp-idf

  Caused by:
      command '"python" "C:\\test\\boop\\.embuild\\espressif\\esp-idf\\release-v5.0\\tools\\idf_tools.py" "--idf-path" "C:\\test\\boop\\.embuild\\espressif\\esp-idf\\release-v5.0" "--non-interactive" "install-python-env"' exited with non-zero status code 1
```

Running the single-quoted command by itself gives the same error: `ERROR: This script was called from a virtual environment, can not create a virtual environment again`

What does this error mean and how might I fix this problem, or otherwise compile esp-idf-template?

Comment: A [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) is a separate installation of Python that may contain its own set of packages. Usually the first step to finding out what your active environment is is to run `where.exe python.exe`, which will show the path to your Python executable. I'm unsure how esp is detecting that it's in a virtual environment, or whether it is doing so correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nathaniel's comment, I found out that I had two installations of python:

```
C:\Users\Me\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

I deleted the platformio installation and was able to build esp-idf-template.